# Dell XPS 9360 External Monitor causes weird colors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dell, hdmi

I plugged my dell xps 13 developer into a projector today and the result was something like 8 bits of color, you can see it here:

[image]

I have the same problem if I connect it to my 46" TV. If I connect it and then turn the TV off and on again, the colors are correct.

It also works when I connect it to my 24" external dell display. Has anyone experienced anything like this?

The adapter that I am using is this one: https://www.startech.com/eu/AV/usb-c-video-adapters/usb-c-hdmi-adapter~CDP2HD

The output of xrandr is:

`Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 1800, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 3200x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   3200x1800     59.98*+  47.99

   2048x1536     60.00

   1920x1440     60.00

DP-1 connected 1920x1080+3200+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1060mm x 626mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98

   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94

   1680x1050     59.88

   1600x900      60.00

   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   ....
   720x400       70.08

HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

Is it a problem that the monitor is recognized as DP-1 instead of HDMI-1?
Dell XPS 13 Developer Kaby Lake. I've tried it with 
Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 16.10 with Kernel 4.4.0-59-generic and 4.8 and 4.9.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, tried Ubuntu 14.04 (preinstalled) and Ubuntu 16.04.2. I use the adapter https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/?iid=221966845000&&&adgroupid=39910041817&rlsatarget=pla-329122148284&abcId=1088896&adtype=pla&merchantid=107329758&poi=&googleloc=1006598&device=c&campaignid=805055692&crdt=0&chn=ps but I remember seeing this laptop work in the past with other adapters at a conference.

Comment: My dmesg output is at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63f12c7827957bc964846553991be765

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-edge/+bug/1661987

Comment: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99137